# how to solve the error java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application when try to run my application, I got following exception.

```
08-12 16:57:41.546  25559-25603/com.ringee.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
    Process: com.ringee.app, PID: 25559
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$4$1.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:169)
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$4$1.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:158)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-12 16:57:41.982  25559-25559/com.ringee.app E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41bfa110 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$4.onClick(ImageUploadActivity.java:156)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)





this is my programming code
```

package com.ringee.app;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.ringee.app.dataaccess.DatabaseHelper;
import com.ringee.app.dataobjects.MediaMO;
import com.ringee.app.dataobjects.UserMO;
import com.ringee.app.delegates.MediaDelegates;
import com.ringee.app.delegates.UserDelegate;
import com.ringee.app.utility.Constants;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
public class ImageUploadActivity extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    //EditText initialized here
    EditText Myusername;
    EditText user;
    private MediaDelegates mediaDelegates = new MediaDelegates();
    private File imgFile;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Context context;
    private UserMO userMO = new UserMO();
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText eText;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    private MediaMO mediaMO = null;
    private UserDelegate userDelegates = new UserDelegate();
    private String text;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.image_upload, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageupload);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Set Progress Dialog Text
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

        prgDialog.show();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                String mediaMo = mediaDelegates.getFileFromServer(userMO, context);
                if (!mediaMo.equals("null")) {
                    mediaMO = gson.fromJson(mediaMo, new TypeToken<MediaMO>() {
                    }.getType());
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(mediaMO.getFileSrcLink());
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i(Constants.TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                } else
                    mediaMO = null;
                Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_user);
                return largeIcon;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
                prgDialog.cancel();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);

        //EditText added here for get current username

        Myusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
        //String s = userMO.getUserName();
        String s=userMO.getUserName();
        Myusername.setText(s);

        Myusername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String str1 = Myusername.getText().toString();

                Intent int1 = new Intent(ImageUploadActivity.this, NameUpdateActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("userdata1", str1);
                int1.putExtras(bundle);
                //(int1);
                startActivityForResult(int1, 0);
            }


        });

        Button buttonAddImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPicture);
        buttonAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                MediaMO mediaMO1 = new MediaMO();
                mediaMO1.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
            }
        });

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                prgDialog.show();
                if (mediaMO == null) {
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            MediaMO mediaMO1 = new MediaMO();
                            mediaMO1.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                            mediaMO1.setIsType(Constants.IS_TYPE_PROFILE_IMAGE);
                            String mediaMo = mediaDelegates.uploadFileToServer(mediaMO1, context, imgFile);
                            if (!mediaMo.equals("null")) {
                                mediaMO = gson.fromJson(mediaMo, new TypeToken<MediaMO>() {
                                }.getType());
                                try {
                                    URL url = new URL(mediaMO.getFileSrcLink());
                                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    connection.connect();
                                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_user);
                            return largeIcon;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
                            prgDialog.cancel();
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }
                    }.execute(null, null, null);
                } else {
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            String mediaMo = mediaDelegates.updateFileToServer(mediaMO, context, imgFile);
                            if (!mediaMo.equals("null")) {
                                mediaMO = gson.fromJson(mediaMo, new TypeToken<MediaMO>() {
                                }.getType());
                                try {
                                    URL url = new URL(mediaMO.getFileSrcLink());
                                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    connection.connect();
                                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_user);
                            return largeIcon;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
                            prgDialog.cancel();
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }
                    }.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            imgFile = new File(picturePath);

        }
    }
```

when runtime i am click to load image buttoni got this  exception.Button buttonLoadImage i am used to load the image can anyone help me how to fix that exception.

Comment: There is a NPE at  at com.ringee.app.ImageUploadActivity$4$1.doInBackground(ImageUploadActivity.java:169). Which code statement is at this line (169)?

Comment: this code "URL url = new URL(mediaMO.getFileSrcLink());" stated this error this code is comes under" buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener"

Answer (score 1):

u should pass the url of image in ur input stream.

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(urlofimage).getContent();
```

return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);